# third US (major) political party

Tags: united-states, parties, voting-systems

Given whole bunch of political deadlocks and big number of non-aligned voters third US party would be good solution of many US problems.

Why there is no even slightest sign of forming such third major political party in USA?

I heard somewhere that there is some law related to government formation which prevents that.
Is that true?

Comment: Dupe... already discussed earlier (can't find ATM(

Comment: It's a good question for a discussion topic, but it really can't be answered in a concrete way.

Comment: Actually, I can answer it concretely as a factor of the electoral system. If you reopen it, I can give an answer.

Comment: @Sam I am do you agree to remove hold on the question so Avi can try to answer that?

Comment: @lowtech - Originally, there weren't supposed to be parties at all, but there have been two major parties since very soon after the constitution was ratified.  See [the US Party System's history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_parties_in_the_United_States#History) on Wikipedia.

Comment: "third US party would be good solution of many US problems" That is highly debatable.  India has a litany of parties, and I don't think anyone would agree that their political system is solving all of their problems.

Comment: Another example is Italy. But it doesn't matter in given situation: there are deadlocks everywhere, no solution of any serious problem can pass. instead of political process usa has lobby companies competition in persuading of certain group of lawmakers to take sides. it is not necessary give good result if any. remember that lobby is all about short-timed interests. lobby company can act in bad faith if money are on the table. this is much harder to do if you are elected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no law preventing the formation of additional parties in the United States. In fact, we have [a number of alternate parties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_party_%28United_States%29), including the Green Party, American Independent Party, and Libertarian Party. However, these parties see few to no electoral victories.

That said, there is very little possibility of a third party viable in the long term. That is because the United States elects its representatives through a plurality ("first-past-the-post") voting system. In the United States, each state is divided into separate districts (the number of districts being roughly proportional to the state's population), and in each district, the candidate who gets the most votes, wins. This system will always trend towards [a two-party system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duverger%27s_law).

If you want a legislative body with multiple parties, you need to have [proportional representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation). There are a number of proportional voting systems, but in general, they let each voter select a party, the party has an ordered list of candidates, and each party is allocated seats to assign to their candidates in proportion to the number of votes the party received. There are some systems that also let you vote for [individual candidates as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-member_proportional_representation), but all of these systems allow for a number of parties.

For an accessible illustration of the way various voting systems work (including their effects on the number of parties), I strongly recommend [CGP Grey's videos](http://www.cgpgrey.com/politics-in-the-animal-kingdom/) on the subject. They're only a few minutes long a piece, and are definitely worth watching.

Comment: have any serious attempts being made in past to change US voting system to allow three or more parties power sharing?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of. It seems to me that wealthy people who have pet parties (see: Ross Perot) would have great interest in advertising an electoral revamp in a state with an initiative process (like California), but perhaps they feel they wouldn't be met with much success, or perhaps the idea hasn't crossed their mind.

Comment: @avi - I think [Approval Voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approval_voting) would be another viable way to introduce more parties while still maintaining the direct election of people (rather than parties) and a plurality system instead of a proportional one.

Comment: @Bobson approval voting is a way to elect single members rather than bodies and cannot guarantee a Condorcet Winner. Though it seems to remove the spoiler effect, I don't know that it doesn't still tend towards a two party system.

Comment: @Avi - My instinct is that it would trend towards a three party system, with the compromise candidate/party becoming the majority, but I'm no expert.

Comment: @Bobson that's interesting, I don't know of a system that's stable at three parties (Except maybe for a proportional system with a sufficiently high threshold), but if you had data, that would be very interesting to look at.

Comment: @Avi - It's basically: one group says "A or B", the other says "C or B", so B wins.  I'll poke around and see if there's any data for it or not.  I could be totally off base, though, since if people were strictly logical, voting would be much simpler.

Comment: You should mention "first past the post" term

Comment: @DVK That just refers to the "plurality" system we use, so I'm not sure where I'd add it without being redundant.

Comment: @Avi - you should for SEO effect. The term is frequently used in discourse on the topic.

Comment: @DVK Changed, hopefully that clarifies something.