# Does the USA have more than 2 political parties (Democrat, Republican)?

Tags: united-states, parties

From the outside it sounds like there are only two political parties in the USA, but you tend to hear of many others in other countries. Are there others that just don't get votes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_parties_in_the_United_States#Modern_U.S._political_party_system

Comment: How is this question that avoids even the most obvious basic research upvoted? :(

Comment: @user4012 In fairness, I thought the goal of StackExchange was to be the leading source of quality answers. That may be niche to stackoverflow though.

Comment: @PhilLello - hover over the downvote button and read the text :)

Comment: Googling "US political parties" will give you the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia has an extensive ["List of political parties in the United States"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_the_United_States). Additional list [is on this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_parties_in_the_United_States#Modern_U.S._political_party_system).

However, the [First-Past-The-Post electoral system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/third-us-major-political-party) (AND in addition, [electoral college as noted in Affable Geek's excellent answer here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/724/would-third-party-candidates-in-the-united-states-fare-better-under-a-proportion)) in US makes any party outside Republicans/Democrats to be largely not viable as far as practical electability.

This isn't always the case and in some exceptional circumstances a 3rd party emerges, [frequently as a result of splintering of one of the two major parties](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/528/what-are-the-main-differences-between-us-first-party-system-and-second-third-par).

Answer (score 5):

As user4012 has pointed out, the use of [plurality voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality_voting_system) in most election has [led to a rigid two-party system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7tWHJfhiyo).  This observation is called [Duverger's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duverger%27s_law).

Since the collapse of the [Whig Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whig_Party_(United_States)) in the 1850's, *every* US president has been either a Democrat or a Republican.

There are a few “third parties” on the ballot in a majority of the states: The [Libertarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_Party_(United_States)), the [Greens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Party_of_the_United_States), and the [Constitution Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_Party_(United_States)).  But they typically receive less than 4% of the vote *combined*.

There have, however, been times in the past when third parties have done better:

- The [Populists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Party_(United_States)) got 8.5% of the popular vote in the 1892 presidential election, and went on to win some governorships and Congressional seats.
- The [Progressives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Party_(United_States,_1912)) came in *second* in the 1912 presidential election as Theodore Roosevelt (formerly a Republican) made a run for a third term.  They did succeed in electing [a California governor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiram_Johnson) and some other state and local offices.
- The [Dixiecrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixiecrat) won a few Southern states in 1948.
- The [American Independent Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Independent_Party), another segregationist party, won the Deep South in 1968.
- [Ross Perot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Perot), founder of the [Reform Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_Party_of_the_United_States_of_America), won 18.9% of the popular vote in 1992.